# Flutter AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? Error

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I am facing many issues since I migrated my project to an Apple Silicon mac. I finally managed to reduce the problems but not sure the answer to this.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in Flutter_the app copy 3...        760ms
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             986ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            1.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
   objc[95181]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x20ba238f0) and ??
   (0x1160dc2b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
   objc[95181]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x20ba23940) and ?? (0x1160dc308). One
   of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
   ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
   note: Using new build system
   note: Building targets in parallel
   note: Planning build
   note: Constructing build description
   error: /Users/gorkem/Documents/flutter_workspace/Flutter_the app copy 3/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:
   unable to open file (in target "Runner" in project "Runner") (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
   error: /Users/gorkem/Documents/flutter_workspace/Flutter_the app copy 3/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:
   unable to open file (in target "Runner" in project "Runner") (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
   error: /Users/gorkem/Documents/flutter_workspace/Flutter_the app copy 3/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:
   unable to open file (in target "Runner" in project "Runner") (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
   warning: Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support
   Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Runner' from project
   'Runner')
   error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support
   Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Runner' from project
   'Runner')
   error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support
   Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Runner' from project
   'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Is there any way to solve this. I am not sure if the problem is even written in there.

Comment: be sure to see simpler, lower-risk answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089767/class-amsupporturlconnectiondelegate-is-implemented-in-both

Answer (score 11):

I was getting this error

**Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib**

**NOTE:**

Try this first if you have updated to flutter 2.10 from <=2.8

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

**Solution:**
Please open podfile and update with this script

```
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
end
```

[image]

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
```

or instead of last command you can try below for M1

```
arch -x86_64 pod install // for M1
```

Run your app.

Comment: I also had the issue with @import firebase_auth. This "AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both" was a warning. Tried eveything, could not resolve. Tried this to clear out the warning atleast. Solved the firebase error also.

Comment: Glad to know that it has fixed your issue.

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work :( 
Still get the same error. App compiles in codemagic but not in my mate's M1. Any other things I could try?

Comment: "arch -x86_64 pod install"
try Run this command as well in /iOS

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same "error output from Xcode build" with my M1 macbook recently as well after updating to Flutter 2.x.

I was able to clear this issue on mine by doing the following:

- Change directory to your project's path and sub-directory:

your_project/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/

- Run $ xattr -lr Runner.app
- Run $ xattr -cr Runner.app

Apparently flutter projects have extended attributes in project app bundles containing Finder info which causes an error.

I found these links that helped for reference.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1940/_index.html
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72492

Comment: Bro u are a saviour. Thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

Try Selecting For install builds only in the run script in the Build phases tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to change:

First check the Dependancy for APNs if need to upgrade. Then Change the version in the POD file and then add

**pod 'GoogleUtilities'**
To the POD target like following:

target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

flutter_install_all_macos_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(**FILE**))
pod 'GoogleUtilities'
end
.

After this Run Flutter pug get and Flutter run. It works for me.

[Ref screenshot for POD file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq5TE.png)