# how to run flutter project in M1 Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, apple-m1

On running the command flutter run in android studio terminal the following error is thrown.
Th device is running on Apple's M1 processor (MacBook Air) using the Rossetta layer.

```
    flutter run      
   Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
   Running Xcode build...                                                  
   Xcode build done.                                           10.7s
   Failed to build iOS app
   Error output from Xcode build:
   ↳
       objc[7304]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x200f40188) and ?? (0x1185702b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
       objc[7304]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x200f401d8) and ?? (0x118570308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
       ** BUILD FAILED **
   
   
   Xcode's output:
   ↳
       /Applications/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/delegate_widget.dart:194:18: Error: Superclass has no method named 'inheritFromElement'.
           return super.inheritFromElement(ancestor, aspect: aspect);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       /Applications/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:259:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class
       'BuildContext'.
        - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/Applications/Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
       Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
               ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as InheritedProvider<T>
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       /Applications/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:260:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined
       for the class 'BuildContext'.
        - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/Applications/Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
       Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
               : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   
       Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
       note: Using new build system
       note: Building targets in parallel
       note: Planning build
       note: Constructing build description
       warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor.
       (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
   
   Could not build the application for the simulator.
   Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089767/class-amsupporturlconnectiondelegate-is-implemented-in-both)

Comment: Didn't worked for me

Comment: Can you provide any more context? What dependencies are you using? Is this a simple or complex project? Have you ever been able to build it successfully? Did this error begin appearing after a change or version upgrade?

Comment: The dependencies I am using are the following : async 2.5.0
  boolean_selector 2.1.0
  characters 1.1.0
  charcode 1.2.0
  clock 1.1.0
  collection 1.15.0
  cupertino_icons 1.0.2
  fake_async 1.2.0
  flutter 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
  flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
  intl 0.15.8 (0.17.0 available)
  matcher 0.12.10
  meta 1.3.0
  path 1.8.0
  provider 3.2.0 (5.0.0 available)
  sky_engine 0.0.99 from sdk flutter
  source_span 1.8.0 (1.8.1 available)
  stack_trace 1.10.0
  stream_channel 2.1.0
  string_scanner 1.1.0
  term_glyph 1.2.0
  test_api 0.2.19 (0.3.0 available)

Comment: typed_data 1.3.0
  vector_math 2.1.0

Comment: I have recently purchased a M1 MacBook, The project was running fine on my previous laptop that was running ubuntu linux in it. But after switching to macOS this problem occurred. If I create a new flutter project and executed flutter run in it then it works fine but not with my previous project

Comment: same issue for me as well in my m1 macbook pro.. existing project not working , new one works @WarMac

Answer (score 0):

When encountering build issues, you can first try running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` to rebuild the project and packages used.
If the Android build runs fine without issues, you can try regenerating the iOS build of the Flutter project. To do this, run `flutter create --platforms=ios [PROJECT]`, then try running the iOS build again.