# I have just set up the working environment for react native for iOS dev on mac but getting this error, while trying to build my first basic app

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

" Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f93a5160) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x113f5c2b8). One of the two will be used "

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089767/class-amsupporturlconnectiondelegate-is-implemented-in-both)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089767/class-amsupporturlconnectiondelegate-is-implemented-in-both)  I used --verbose and the detailed error message was like "The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'YogaKit' from project 'Pods')
".
This was for Xcode version 12. To resolve this, at the end of the pod file we can add below code(screenshot attached):

```js
post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
        t.build_configurations.each do |bc|
            if bc.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] == '8.0'
                bc.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.4'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And then go to project_name/ios directory and run "pod update" after that "cd .." to go back to project_name directory and run the react-native commands "npx react-native start" and after that preferably in a new terminal window run "npx react-native run-ios". This shall resolve the issue.