# Xcode with Apple M1 error: Class is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework

Tags: xcode, macos, gfortran, xcode12.5

In Terminal getting the following message running code using `gfortran`. Seems to be an Xcode 12.5 on Big Sur and M1 chip:

```
objc[1554]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f2022c10) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1147bc2b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1554]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f2022c60) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1147bc308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

suggestions?

Comment: possibly of use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089767/class-amsupporturlconnectiondelegate-is-implemented-in-both

Answer (score 1):

My issue was related to changing the username on my Mac account. I resolved this by deleting the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem.
Force delete everything in `~/.pub-cahe/hosted/pub.dartlang.org`
and then in the project in the `flutter pub get` console