# Mac M1 -- Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.(Flutter.h and AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate, AMSupportURLSession) issue

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, apple-m1, flutter-ios

I am new to ios development with flutter. While trying to build the app on ios simulator and external device (iphone xr), I get the following error--

```
objc[50354]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x1f3d2c188) and ?? (0x1184482b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[50354]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1f3d2c1d8) and ?? (0x118448308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    FirebaseAnalytics-framework-aginbutuetuehmfqavbftszulegx
    /Users/.../ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal error: module 'cloud_firestore' not found
    @import cloud_firestore;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    FirebaseAnalytics-framework-aginbutuetuehmfqavbftszulegx
    /Users/.../ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal error: module 'cloud_firestore' not found
    @import cloud_firestore;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    FirebaseAnalytics-framework-aginbutuetuehmfqavbftszulegx
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Along with this, I am getting error in XCode AppDelegate.swift where it says-- "Flutter.h not found"

I am stuck on this issue for 2 weeks now and have tried almost all the solutions available to the problem.

Please help!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Using an M1 Apple Silicon chip, you may face those [compiling errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089767/class-amsupporturlconnectiondelegate-is-implemented-in-both) about the  Class `AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate` or `AMSupportURLSession` Class being implemented twice:

My trick to remove this issue is to use rosetta and recreate some files in your Flutter project.

Here's what to do:

Be sure you have a correct apple profile in your XCode Proj. (for code signing)
Be sure that you are [opening terminal using Rosetta and not with ARM/Native](https://medium.com/codex/simple-way-to-use-cocoapods-on-m1-ac9e22cf7e1c)

Then, and only then, try to run this command:

```dart
flutter clean && rm ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock && rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace && flutter run
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I solved the problem by a combination of things which included your answer too. It turns out it is a problem in M1 as it is heavily cache dependent. What worked for me was using system's terminal (I was using terminal through android studio earlier) and running all my commands there. I had to clear the system cache (by cleaning ~/Library/Caches) as a lot of the changes I made didn't reflect due to the cache being unchanged. Hence why the most common solution is to recreate iOS folder. I learned a lot about mac and M1 in particular by encountering this problem. Thnx