# objc[14025]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

> objc[14025]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1efb7ac10) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x12c2b82b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. objc[14025]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1efb7ac60) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x12c2b8308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. ** BUILD FAILED **

Solutions i tried:

- flutter clean inside the project directory.
- Flutter pub get Pod update
- Pod update
- Pod repo update
- Restarted Xcode and Mac
- pod install
- flutter build ios

I tried flutter clean, pod update, install, i couldn't run the app on ios emulator,. every time i get the same error again and again. Its not an issue with info plist or but i couldn't find the exact problem,. Tried almost all the possible solution from various sources, I have been sitting n this one issue for the past 3 days.. Please if any body could help... It will be really helpful. Please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089767/class-amsupporturlconnectiondelegate-is-implemented-in-both

Answer (score 2):

Didi you post the full error message? I had a similar error message. However, in my case the full error log contained a message about Xcode missing an architecture necessary to build this project for the iOS Simulator:

```
    Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[7363]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f92f2b90)
    and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1079b42c8).
    One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[7363]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f92f2be0) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1079b4318). One of
    the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/ralfweinbrecher/Development/flutter-projects/infoapp/ios/Runner.xcodeproj: error: The linked framework
    'Pods_Runner.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64. (in target 'Runner'
    from project 'Runner')
```

Here Xcode complains about missing the arm64 platform. I fixed this with adding the following line to my Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT'] = 'dwarf'
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
        # This line was added!
         config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
       config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
     end  
   end
end
```

After fixing the problem of the missing architecture the other error message was gone too.

Answer (score 1):

Well!I had a similar issue.I execute flutter build ios is successful in macOS's terminal,but an error occurred in jenkins,the build of command is the same.
you should check your compilie environment first,try flutter doctor,and then make sure that your environment is well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEQdB.png)

Comment: Please add more specific steps for the asker to check on their environment.  Please add a better description for your image link than the default.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I was able to solve this by **duplicate the terminal and check "Open using Rosetta"** for the duplicated terminal, solution as described in one of the steps of this link: https://hackernoon.com/apple-m1-chip-how-to-install-homebrew-using-rosetta-su12331b.

In my case was some sort of "log noise" when I was trying to run fastlane for iOS. That didn't stop me from completing my build and uploading it to the AppStore, but it was quite annoying to receive the same message every time I run the command in the terminal.

This worked for me, hope for you too.

Answer (score 0):

After stumbling around trying a menagerie of solutions from the web, I reinstalled Xcode and the CommandLineTools clean and then also made sure to `gem uninstall cocoapods` from any ruby environment.  That, at long last, seems to have cleared the errors for me.

macOS 12.3 Beta (21E5206e)
M1 MacBook Pro 2021 M1 Max
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)

Works in either i386 or amd64 arch under /bin/zsh.

UPDATE

After doing more testing, I can see that it very much is related to your arch, as it mentioned below and elsewhere.  With a completely clean command line tools, xcode, arm64 brew, rbenv and cocoapods, the error appears under an arm64 shell and /NOT/ under an i386 shell.  It is fine to run it as an -x86_64 command under the default arm64 shell directly as well: `arch -x86_64 xcrun xcodebuild`

What is still needed to be diagnosed/fixed now is that flutter (where I started this journey) explicitly runs all these commands as an arm64 arch now, so things break/hang unexpectedly...

FWIW, knowing what I have now learned, I can point you to the well written and maintained [cocoapods troubleshooting guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html) as it is really well done.