# g++ shows a strange message

Tags: c++, terminal, compiler-errors, g++

sometimes when I compile with g++ it shows the following message then runs normally after a couple seconds.

```
gursimarmiglani@Gursimars-MacBook-Pro point % g++ main.cc
objc[1111]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1f934b130) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10624c2c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1111]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1f934b180) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10624c318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1112]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1f934b130) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1084ec2c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1112]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1f934b180) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1084ec318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

means?

Comment: Here's a similar issue: [Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089767/class-amsupporturlconnectiondelegate-is-implemented-in-both) though they get this message when building with flutter.

Comment: So what is this error? I have this with no reference to flutter.